# BoDi.ObjectContainerException Interface cannot be resolved: OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, bdd, specflow

I am creating a new framework as PageFactory has been deprecated.
I am getting the error

```
BoDi.ObjectContainerException : Interface cannot be resolved: OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver (resolution path: UnitTestProject1.Base)
TearDown : BoDi.ObjectContainerException : Interface cannot be resolved: OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver (resolution path: UnitTestProject1.Base)
```

My code snippet of my framework is below.  I am not sure how I can resolve this.  I am aware I could use Context Injection but am not sure what attributes from my framework I should move and to where.
I was thinking should I move the IWedriver Driver to a class and call this in a constructor but not sure where I should call it in the steps file.

Some help to resolve this issue appreciated, thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using SeleniumExtras.PageObjects;


namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    public class Base : SpecflowBaseTest
    {
        protected IWebDriver driver { get; set; }

    public Base(IWebDriver Driver)
    {
        driver = Driver;
        //PageFactory.InitElements(Driver, this);
    }
   }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using UnitTestProject1.Page;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using BoDi;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
[Binding]
public class SpecflowBaseTest : TechTalk.SpecFlow.Steps
{
    // For additional details on SpecFlow hooks see 
http://go.specflow.org/doc-hooks
    protected IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }
    private readonly IObjectContainer objectContainer;

    [BeforeScenario]
    public void BeforeScenario()
    {
        Driver = new ChromeDriver();
        //this.objectContainer = objectContainer;
        //ObjectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs<IWebDriver>(Driver);
        Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    }

    [AfterScenario]
    public void AfterScenario()
    {
        Driver.Close();
        Driver.Quit();
    }

    public void NavigateToURL(string URL)
    {
        Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);
    }

    protected LoginPage LoginPage => new LoginPage(Driver);
  }
}

using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;


namespace UnitTestProject1.Steps
{
[Binding, Parallelizable]

public class LoginSteps : SpecflowBaseTest
{
    [Given(@"I navigate to (.*)")]
    public void GivenINavigateToHttpsCompany_Com(string URL)
    {
        NavigateToURL(URL);
    }

    [Given(@"I enter bw_(.*) and (.*)")]
    public void GivenIEnterBw_Valid_UserAnd(string Username, string 
Password)
    {
        LoginPage.Login(Username, Password);
    }

    [Then(@"I am logged in as bw_valid_user")]
    public void ThenIAmLoggedInAsBw_Valid_User()
    {
        //LoginPage.
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize a new `IWebDriver` object and register it with SpecFlow's dependency injection framework in a `[BeforeScenario]`.

```cs
[Binding]
public class SeleniumSpecFlowHooks
{
    private readonly IObjectContainer container;

    public SeleniumSpecFlowHooks(IObjectContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    [BeforeScenario]
    public void CreateWebDriver()
    {
        // Create and configure a concrete instance of IWebDriver
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(...)
        {
            ...
        };

        // Make this instance available to all other step definitions
        container.RegisterInstance(driver);
    }

    [AfterScenario]
    public void DestroyWebDriver()
    {
        IWebDriver driver = container.Resolve<IWebDriver>();

        driver.Close();
        driver.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Your step definition classes should not be initializing the web driver. Just declare an `IWebDriver` argument in their constructors.

Base class:

```cs
[Binding]
public class SpecflowBaseTest : TechTalk.SpecFlow.Steps
{
    protected IWebDriver Driver { get; }
    protected LoginPage LoginPage { get; }

    public SpecflowBaseTest(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        Driver = driver;
        LoginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
    }

    public void NavigateToURL(string URL)
    {
        Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);
    }
}
```

Child class:

```cs
[Binding, Parallelizable]
public class LoginSteps : SpecflowBaseTest
{
    [Given(@"I navigate to (.*)")]
    public void GivenINavigateToHttpsCompany_Com(string URL)
    {
        NavigateToURL(URL);
    }

    [Given(@"I enter bw_(.*) and (.*)")]
    public void GivenIEnterBw_Valid_UserAnd(string Username, string Password)
    {
        LoginPage.Login(Username, Password);
    }

    [Then(@"I am logged in as bw_valid_user")]
    public void ThenIAmLoggedInAsBw_Valid_User()
    {
        //LoginPage.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have followed your solution.  I am getting 1 error in the LoginSteps class when do a build.  The error is There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'driver' of 'SpecflowBaseTest.SpecflowBaseTest(IWebDriver)' UnitTestProject1 D:\Selenium Projects\framework\Olympus\UnitTestProject1\UnitTestProject1\Steps\LoginSteps.cs

Comment: @OptimusAutomation: What type is the `driver` you are passing? In the code you posted in your question, it looks like the LoginPage object is being initialized in the parent class. Without seeing your code I can't help you. You could try posting another question.

Comment: I have posted a new questions.  Link here, thanks.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56490851/error-cs7036-there-is-no-argument-given-that-corresponds-to-the-required-formal

Answer (score 0):

solved by creating a new class

```
using BoDi;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

namespace DoclerQAtests
{

    [Binding]
    public class WebDriverSupport
    {
        private readonly IObjectContainer objectContainer;
        private ChromeDriver webdriver;

        public WebDriverSupport(IObjectContainer objectContainer)
        {
            this.objectContainer = objectContainer;
        }

        [BeforeScenario]
        public void InitializeWebDriver()
        {
            this.webdriver = new ChromeDriver();
            objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs<IWebDriver>(webdriver);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this issue was resolved by adding a class level field `public IWebDriver Driver` instead of a local method level `driver`.

```
[Binding]
public class DriverSetup
{
    private IObjectContainer _objectContainer;
    public IWebDriver Driver;

    public DriverSetup(IObjectContainer objectContainer)
    {
        _objectContainer = objectContainer;

    }

    [BeforeScenario]
    public void BeforeScenario()
    {
        //TODO please supply your Sauce Labs user name in an environment variable
        var sauceUserName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SAUCE_USERNAME", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
        //TODO please supply your own Sauce Labs access Key in an environment variable
        var sauceAccessKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
        var sauceOptions = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            ["username"] = sauceUserName,
            ["accessKey"] = sauceAccessKey
        };
        var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions
        {
            BrowserVersion = "latest",
            PlatformName = "Windows 10"
        };
        chromeOptions.AddAdditionalOption("sauce:options", sauceOptions);

        Driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("https://ondemand.saucelabs.com/wd/hub"),
            chromeOptions.ToCapabilities(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        _objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs(Driver);
    }
}
```