# Taking Screenshot in Nunit BDD specflow and attached to the DevoOps Test result

Tags: tfs, nunit, devops, bdd, specflow

I'm using NUnit.net core BDD spec flow I need help to capture a screenshot of the failed scenario step and attached to the TFS result report in DevOps.I have the code below.

```cs
public bool loginpageelementpresent()
{
    try
    {
        return loginpageelement.Displayed;
    } 
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        var filePath = $"{TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory}\\{TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.MethodName}.jpg";

        ((ITakeScreenshot)_driver).GetScreenshot().SaveAsFile(filePath);

        TestContext.AddTestAttachment(filePath);

        return false;
    }
}
```

Using this code I'm able to see screenshot in DevOps but I want to use this code to be applicable to all the failed scenario steps can someone explain to me how to make it more dynamic so if any scenario step get failed it automatically take a screenshot and attached to the DevOps Test Result

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to accomplish this in an [after scenario hook](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/Hooks.html):

```cs
[Binding]
public class SpecFlowHooks
{
    private readonly IObjectContainer container;
    private readonly ScenarioContext scenario;

    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

    private bool IsFailingScenario => scenario.TestError != null;

    public SpecFlowHooks(IObjectContainer container, ScenarioContext scenario)
    {
        this.container = container;
        this.scenario = scenario;
    }

    [BeforeScenario]
    public void CreateWebDriver()
    {
        // Create and configure the Selenium IWebDriver object
        var driver = new ChromeDriver() or FirefoxDriver() or EdgeDriver() or whatever you normally do

        // Make the web driver available to all step definitions, including this
        // hooks classes. Additionally flag this object as something BoDi should
        // dispose of at the end of each test.
        container.RegisterInstanceAs<IWebDriver>(driver, null, true);
    }

    [AfterScenario]
    public void RecordTestFailure()
    {
        if (IsFailingScenario)
        {
            var driver = container.Resolve<IWebDriver>();
            var photographer = (ITakeScreenshot)driver;
            var filePath = $"{TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory}\\{TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.MethodName}.jpg";

            photographer.GetScreenshot()
                        .SaveAsFile(filePath);

            TestContext.AddTestAttachment(filePath);
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming that adding an attachment to the test context will indeed add the screenshot to the test results in DevOps. Incidentally, this is also a good opportunity to learn about dependency injection in SpecFlow and how to properly initialize and manage an IWebDriver object in your SpecFlow tests.

I answered another question that gives you a more complete picture of initializing the web driver, and then using it in your step definitions and Selenium page models: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56427437/3092298